# Title bar of UWP app is overlayed by main page

Tags: uwp, titlebar

I just noticed that my UWP app has "lost" its title bar. The minimize/maximize/exit buttons are there, but the main bar (along with app title) is invisible. It looks like it is overlayed by the main page of the app.

I was in the middle of trying to add a custom Hamburger menu to the title bar when I happened to notice this. I've since restored the xaml file back to the original but still the title bar has disappeared. Something simple and stupid, I'm sure but what?

Comment: This happens when you set ExtendViewIntoTitleBar to true  if you don't want it, then don't set it to true.

Comment: Also happens when tablet mode is on.

Comment: strange that same app looks fine on Surface4 pro; titlebar is there.
it is only on my development pc that the titlebar is invisible.

Comment: also, i have searched the entire solution for ExtendViewIntoTitleBar and could not find it. i do not use it.  any hidden place i should look?

Comment: If you still have the problem, please share a [mcve] so that we can reproduce your issue.